# Django redirect is not passing keyword parameters

Tags: python, django

I am redirecting from a view in one app, to a view in another. Its finding the view just fine but not passing the arguments. I've tried passing it as positional and keyword but cant get the thing to work.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=pass1)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            print(user.username, type(user.username), file=sys.stderr)
            return redirect(reverse('homepage'), user.username)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Bad Credentials!")
            return redirect('index')
```

```
@login_required()
def homepage(request, username=None):
    print(username, file=sys.stderr)
    try:
        user = userAttribute.objects.get(username=username)
    except userAttribute.DoesNotExist:
        
        return redirect("index")
```

[14/Feb/2024 18:15:18] "GET /signin HTTP/1.1" 200 824

Kane <class 'str'>

[14/Feb/2024 18:15:23] "POST /signin HTTP/1.1" 302 0

None

Comment: You want the client to POST after the redirect?  Then that should be a 308, but you're returning a 302.

Comment: I believe you need to pass username specifically as a keyword argument in the redirect call, ie you need `username=user.username` instead of `user.username` as the second argument to `redirect()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have tried doing both username=user.username and just using positional but neither work.

Comment: @erik258 The user posts to def signin with username and password, then I want to pass this to homepage so I can use the info. My problem is strictly that redirect is not passing def homepage the username.

Comment: Okay then 302 is what you want.  If you want [`redirect` to pass a value as a keyword argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) you should give it a keyword `return redirect(reverse('homepage'), username=user.username)`

Comment: @erik258 from my post ". I've tried passing it as positional and keyword but cant get the thing to work." Ive used username=user.name, and in the homepage view ive used (username=None) (username) and (**kwargs). All of them turn up empty.